# create directory ‘Folder’: No space left on device

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage, storage

I have a weird error.
My website (in /var/www/html) is being unavailable every morning, i checked the logs and logs are empty.
Then I tried to create a folder in home directory and it says: `create directory ‘Foldert’: No space left on device`

With `df` command I get this, I guess i'm using /dev/sda1 Filesystem

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             4059096        0   4059096   0% /dev
tmpfs             814308      684    813624   1% /run
/dev/sda1       30308240 14777716  15514140  49% /
tmpfs            4071532        0   4071532   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            4071532        0   4071532   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15        106858     3668    103190   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs             814304        0    814304   0% /run/user/1000
```

If I run `df -i` i get the following results:

```
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           1014774     433 1014341    1% /dev
tmpfs          1017883     674 1017209    1% /run
/dev/sda1      3870720 1029416 2841304   27% /
tmpfs          1017883       1 1017882    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          1017883       4 1017879    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          1017883      18 1017865    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15           0       0       0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs          1017883      11 1017872    1% /run/user/1000
```

On `var/www/html` folder the size is just 6.8gb.
And as you can see, just 27% of the partition is being used.
So what can I do?
I'm using Ubuntu 18
Hope you can help me.
Greetings!

Comment: The ext filesystems can run out of inodes if there are many small files in your system, yet show what you describe. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109349/why-does-the-linux-kernel-report-out-of-disk-space-when-in-reality-it-is-out-o  Which filesystem are you using? Please click [edit] and advise. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: done, please check updated question

Comment: Do you see any errors in the output of the `dmesg --follow` command when you try this? Data corruption could at least theoretically cause this. Can you also clarify the symptoms of your website being unavailable?

Comment: I don't think what I see are errors, and the site is unavailable because the space was full, also logs from my website were 0kb, that means it could not write new files, after deleting some backups it worked back again.

Comment: Would recommend running a forced filesystem check on the device if possible..